# Bootstrap 5: how do I make cards in a row have variable width?

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I want to have two cards, one representing a table of contents and a second one representing some text. Sometimes the first one is significantly longer in height than the second one. How can I make the cards vary in width? At the moment they align to the same width, leaving a lot of empty white space on one of the cards.

Comment: Please post your code in the question

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by aligning both cards by the top